# My Joomla site is stacked in the corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

I'm not really sure how else to explain it, but about every 5 or so clicks on my site and the page stacks itself in the upper left corner as such:

[image]

It doesn't matter what browser I use. CSS appears to be loading. Simply refreshing the page fixes it, but it will keep coming back after a few more clicks.

Has anyone seen this before??

[phoenixmag.com](http://phoenixmag.com)

Comment: Working perfectly fine for me on Firefox 46. Try clearing your browser cache. Although I wasn't too sure what you meant by "every 5 clicks". So I just started clicking everywhere on the page

Comment: Ya, thats what I do. I just randomly click links on the site and sooner or later this pops up. It's not just me, I've seen it on other machines, including my laptop at home. Clearing the cache does not fix it.

Comment: I forgot to add that I use cloudflare as well. I have purged that cache as well with no luck.

Comment: Try disabling the cache completely and see if that helps. If it doesn't, then what I suspect is a rogue JavaScript file causing this problem.

Comment: Unable to replicate any of the problems you describe (Edge, Chrome and Firefox) and without the effected CSS/HTML code attached to the question its unclear and too board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO the problem was a bad script in a rotating ad. This is why it only came up occasionally. Once that ad was removed the site returned to normal. Thank you itoctopus for the insight. I found it after reading your post and going through modules one by one until I found it.